# Determining if a line has wrapped in a browser

Tags: html, css

Is there any programmatic method for determining if a line has wrapped in the browser it is being displayed in?  The content below this line is absolutely positioned (for purposes of source-ordering) and I need to change its position if the line wraps.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You can determine if an element was wrapped by checking its height and comparing it to a similar element with the same content but wider.

This is how you can do it:

1. Create a hidden element with the same content and style as the the one you want to check, but with a really big `width` value.
2. Append that created element to the element that contains the line or paragraph.
3. Compare the heights of the elements (if they are the same, no wrapping; if they are different, the line was wrapped).
4. Remove the created element.

For example:

```js
function checkWrapping() {

    // for each paragraph in the div, check if it was wrapped
    $("#mydiv").find("p").each(function () {

        // create a hidden paragraph with the same text and append it to the parent
        var aux = $("<p style='display:none;position:absolute;width:10000000px'>" + $(this).text() + "</p>");
        $(this).parent().append(aux);

        // compare the height of the paragrap with the height of the one-line paragraph
        if ($(this).height() > $(aux).height()) {
            console.log($(this).attr("id") + " is wrapped!");
        } else {
            console.log($(this).attr("id") + " is NOT wrapped!");
        }

        // remove the hidden paragraph at the end of the check
        $(aux).remove();
    });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mydiv">
    <p id="p0">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tristique rutrum velit, sit amet vestibulum dui consectetur at. Suspendisse scelerisque pellentesque lectus in lacinia.</p>
    <p id="p1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p id="p2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Pellentesque tristique rutrum velit, sit amet vestibulum dui consectetur at.</p>
</div>
<input type="button" value="check if wrapped" onclick="checkWrapping();">
```

You can see the sample also on this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o1ay0e71/ (it will allow you to resize the window easily to compare results).

Also, if the line has html tags, use `.html()` instead of `.text()` as shown on this update: http://jsfiddle.net/o1ay0e71/1/

Comment: Very nice solution.  Is there a way to do this without javascript?

Comment: If you mean exclusively with CSS/HTML: not that I know of.